# Any way to recover data from a semi-bricked iPhone?

Tags: iphone, data-recovery

My iPhone turns on, shows the white apple logo, and then after a few minutes shuts off. It is not a battery issue, it happens even when it's plugged in.

Is there any way I can get the data off the phone without resorting to a hard-drive recovery company?

Maybe some kind of program that can access the hard drive through the USB port? Or maybe I can open up the phone and somehow get the data off the hard drive?

I know that I can restore the phone through iTunes and have it working again. The problem is that I didn't back up the data so I have 400 or so notes saved only on the phone. If I restore it, they will be gone forever.

Just in case you are wondering, I haven't jailbroken or even attempted to jailbreak the phone. This problem just happened randomly while I was using the phone. It was frozen one day, I tried a hard reset, and ever since then I can never get it to work. I read that some people got the same issue via a remote wipe, however, I'm not subscribed to mobile me, so there is no way that could have happened.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an Apple store in proximity, book an appointment with their tech. If PhoneView does not recognize the phone, I believe this may be your best chance to get the data out.

Comment: Already did, they referred me to a hard drive recovery company. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a late answer for those following in your footsteps (like me).

Huzzah! Editing my previously negative answer to report success! SSH in and get YOUR data off YOUR phone, thanks to a great tool that's so new it doesn't have a cool name yet: shh_rd. [The author's blog post](http://msftguy.blogspot.co.nz/2012/01/automatic-ssh-ramdisk-creation-and.html) has a video walk-through.

If ssh_rd wasn't available, then Apple might be your best bet if your bricked iPhone is under warranty. If you have a 3GS or newer then a forensics specialist is probably necessary. Details below ...

There are very few tools that can access iOS device data directly - and these are usually available only to law enforcement and forensics agencies. (Though there is some interesting work being done on Linux with a library called [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/).)

One is [iOS Forensic Research](http://www.iosresearch.org/) maintained by [Jonathan Zdziarski](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/) who wrote the (now dated) book on the subject of "[iPhone Forensics](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596153595.do)". Another is the [Elcomsoft iOS Forensic Toolkit](http://www.elcomsoft.com/eift.html). There are also hardware assisted solutions like [Cellebrite UFED](http://www.cellebrite.com/mobile-forensics-products/forensics-products.html).

Assuming you don't have access to these kinds of tools, the last resort is to restore the iPhone using iTunes, then jailbreak it and [dump the filesystem](http://log.ijulien.com/post/182804914/iphone-3gs-data-recovery). The 3GS and newer models use hardware to [encrypt their filesystems](http://www.prweb.com/releases/iPhone/forensics/prweb8470927.htm) so recovery is probably not feasible.

Filesystem dumps from phones prior to the 3GS can be scanned for files using software like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into a program like [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to see if it can access data on the phone?

Comment: Both PhoneView and iTunes don't detect that a phone is connected.