# Can I get files off an iPhone 4 that is stuck in a firmware update loop?

Tags: itunes, iphone, software-update, error

So I updated my iPhone 4 to iOS6 today (using the built in updater on the iPhone). The phone did some stuff for a while and then rebooted with a progress bar which never updates. If I leave it long enough it reboots and then shows that bar again.

Annoyingly I have some stuff on that I didn't back up, is there any way to fix this? Even if I didn't care about the data on the phone, I can't get iTunes to do anything and the phone will just reboot to this progress bar screen.

Not once have I had any error codes from iTunes. I'm more concerned with the data at this point and can probably force the device into restore mode once I have the files I need.

Comment: Also this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1762/any-way-to-recover-data-from-a-semi-bricked-iphone

Comment: _Next time_ consider setting up your phone to do automatic synchronization with iTunes over WiFi.  Very convenient and unintrusive.

Comment: This was just a test phone from my work and so wasn't synced to anyone's machine. I'm aware of how it works and use it on my own devices! Anyway, I managed to get the data off using Wondershare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm that my solution was to use an excellent 3rd party tool, although costly...

http://www.wondershare.com/data-recovery/iphone-data-recovery.html

It managed to extract the data from my iPhone 4. Because the iPhone was trying to update, I forced it into DFU mode which this application uses to get the data.

My next step is to do a restore, which I don't mind doing now! :D

Comment: You could've used DiskAid. It has a fully functioning trial.

Comment: Not seen it, wondershare was the same however. Trial shows what you can get, but you need to buy to actually get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is resolved by a second restore after you reboot your computer. Of course, you might wait things out if you don't have a backup and there is *any chance whatsoever* the phone will complete this update without risk of losing the data on the phone (contacts, app information, documents, etc...)

To be sure you (and I) haven't skipped a step, you will want to do everything on this page.

- [iTunes: Restoring iOS software](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414)

Pay attention to the link at the bottom should you get there about putting the device into recovery mode. That will wipe everything, so don't do that unless you have a good backup from this morning (or whenever you started the update process).

Comment: What do you mean by `Usually this is resolved by a second restore after you reboot your computer.` - is there comms between the device and the machine while the progress bar is showing?

Comment: There can be at many times in the restore cycle. It depends on which pass. You can find the details in a restore log on the computer, but often the problem with a restore is on the computer side, not the phone side, so the reboot there ensures as clean a start - freshly loaded USB drivers, etc... Basically power off both and start again once you are sure this pass should be aborted.

Comment: But I did the update over the air, so there's nothing that has changed on the machine I'm using. I've only just thought to put the new iTunes on but again, nothing is asking me to use iTunes, the machine doesn't even notice the device being plugged in!

Comment: I managed to put the device into dfu mode which tells me that I need to restore the device. This means I can probably restore from here, but is it safe to say that my data is already lost?

Comment: Yes - DFU is when the screen is totally black. You shouldn't need to go there as normal restore handles this 98% of the time. If iTunes says restore it will wipe whatever data is still left. Only if it says update will anything be preserved.

Comment: Additionally DFU is more dangerous - more can go wrong and you have no safety net. Computer burp, cable pull at the wrong moment and you have a paperweight. I'd always have a genius DFU your device since if they break it, they might feel bad and replace it. If you break it in DFU mode you're really outside even warranty support territory. This is as far as I can recommend to most people to go: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1808

Comment: I've dealt with DFU in the past (other reasons such as jb) and putting the phone into DFU mode is the only way I can get a machine to recognize it! I understand though that a restore would not be ideal for me here! That for the info anyway!

Comment: Also, just a note, the phone in question wasn't jailbroken!

Comment: Also, I've just used a tool called Wondershare Dr.Fone which is showing me my data! I just need to pay them $60 now to get it off my phone! Probably worth it though :D